# Querying Firebase db without sync angularfire2

Tags: firebase, angularfire2

I am using angularfire2 for my ionic application, I am able to query the realtime database with `this.angularFireDatabase.list('/users/')`.

However I want the database need not to be synced, i.e. just want to query the database once and close the synchronized connection. 
I can do the same in android as `reference.sync(false);`.

I have been going through their documentation however couldn't find anything there.

**Full Solution as per the answer**

```
getUsers(): Promise<any[]> {
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  let subscription = this.afd.list('/users/', { preserveSnapshot: true }).take(1).subscribe(data => {
    let retArray: any[] = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
      retArray.push(data[i].toJSON());
    }
    subscription.unsubscribe();
    return resolve(retArray);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/issues/380), you can use the RxJS filtering operator [`take`](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/take.md):

```
this.af.database.object('/users/', { preserveSnapshot: true).take(1);
```

This also kills the subscription after the first value has emitted.

Remember to import the `take`-operator:

```
import 'rxjs/add/operator/take';
```

Comment: Great...worked like a charm...Thanks..I will update the actual service code in a while.